# The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: Empty

Tags: android, build.gradle

I get the warning "The following project options are deprecated and have been removed:" when compiling my Android project. Problem is I have nothing more. I was expecting the name of the module(s) generating this warning but nothing... Can you please help me to remove that warning?

[image]

Comment: What is your gradle version

Comment: Version is 5.4.1

Comment: Applied all suggested updates in project structure window but not better!